# Android UI Automate - run test on HW device without using the ADB shell

Tags: android, adb, android-uiautomator

I've started to test my app using android UI Automate tool and managed to create a test and run it through the ADB shell on the HW device.
I wanted to ask if there is a way to run the test on the device itself without using the ADB shell? 
thanks!

Comment: Some time ago I was able to run GNURoot on android. From there connect via adb to phone and run tests. So phone drive itself. No root needed. Some problem with routing, hacked with share connectivity via usb in android if I remember well.

Comment: You can make an app and start activites and invoke your tests..

Comment: with `--nohup` as command argument, you can start the test and remove cable. test will be still running.